# MySQL update two different tables at once (CRUD)

Tags: php, mysql, join, crud

I have two tables like this:

```
[tblFacilityHrs] id uid title description

[tblFacilityHrsDateTimes] owner_uid startEventDate endEventDate startTime endTime days recurrence finalDate
```

I've joined the table as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblFacilityHrs JOIN tblFacilityHrsDateTimes ON tblFacilityHrs.uid =tblFacilityHrsDateTimes.owner_uid") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

To display both tables I go through each record and put it all in a table:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
foreach($row AS $key => $value) { $row[$key] = stripslashes($value); } 
echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['title']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['description']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['startEventDate']) . "</td>";
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['endEventDate']) . "</td>"; 
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['startTime']) . "</td>";     
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['endTime']) . "</td>"; 
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['days']) . "</td>";     
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['recurrence']) . "</td>";   
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['finalDate']) . "</td>";
```

My question is now, how do I edit each record?

In my main page under the table I would normally do this:

**pseudo code**

```
echo "<td valign='top'><a href=edit.php?id={$row['id']}>Edit</a></td><td><a href=delete.php?id={$row['id']}>Delete</a></td> ";
```

Then on my edit page I would do something like this:

**pseudo code**

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) ) { 
    $id = (int) $_GET['id']; 
    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { 
    foreach($_POST AS $key => $value) { $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value); } 
    $sql = "`title` =  '{$_POST['title']}' ,  `description` =  '{$_POST['description']}'   WHERE `id` = '$id' "; 
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
    echo (mysql_affected_rows()) ? "Edited row.<br />" : "Nothing changed. <br />"; 
    echo "<a href='list.php'>Back</a>";
```

How does this work since the tables are joined? How can I edit both of them?

Comment: I don't know how it works since the value you assign to `$sql` is not a valid query. Bad copy-paste?

Comment: It's not suppose to work the last two code blocks were just examples of something I would do if I only had one table.

Comment: Good you worried about `mysql_real_escape`, but if you need placeholders (i.e. "what I should be putting there is what I'm asking for"), then flag them appropriately in the snippets. Currently it's confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should update each Table seperatly ; first the master table and then the detail table , and after that reabind your dataview

Comment: Wow. What happens in concurrent situations (e.g. when another client might read from the tables between the first and second update)?

Comment: @Romain you can perform the updates in a transaction which will respect an operation's atomicity

Comment: @watcher Yes, that's exactly what I want - a blurb about transactions in the answer.

Comment: @Romain well , you can use Ajax and and a timer or event mechanism to update your other clients view of the data if this is that important to you for your clients to view the correct information !

Comment: @khashayar The correct answer is "you wrap your updates in a transaction". Everything else is brittle & bound to give you headaches.